# Supabase Self-Hosted Connection to Default Project (Still connecting)?

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

## I deploy supabase to digitalocean

.env:

```
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=MY_PASSWORD
JWT_SECRET=MY_JWT_SECRET
ANON_KEY=MY_ANON_KEY
SERVICE_ROLE_KEY=MY_SERVICE_ROLE_KEY

## General
SITE_URL=http://mydropletip:3000
ADDITIONAL_REDIRECT_URLS=
JWT_EXPIRY=3600
DISABLE_SIGNUP=false
API_EXTERNAL_URL=http://mydropletip:8000

STUDIO_PORT=3000
# replace if you intend to use Studio outside of localhost
SUPABASE_PUBLIC_URL=http://mydropletip:8000
```

volumes/api/kong.yml:

```
consumers:
  - username: anon
    keyauth_credentials:
      - key: MY_ANON_KEY
  - username: service_role
    keyauth_credentials:
      - key: MY_SERVICE_ROLE
```

When I run docker compose up -d I got this

[image]

But It's still connecting?

[image]

How to fix it? Thank you for reply

Answer (score 0):

Please check your kong api port

##### API Proxy - Configuration for the Kong Reverse proxy.

KONG_HTTP_PORT=8090

If it is changed from default port 8000, make sure to update
SUPABASE_PUBLIC_URL=http://localhost:8090
API_EXTERNAL_URL=http://localhost:8090

In digital ocean, please check if ufw is enabled on the ports listed in the config file.

```
sudo ufw allow 8090
```